# Dynamically create some types of array and return that array as a collection of arrays

Tags: object-oriented, c++

As an example, I have database select query that returns **n** columns and I didn't know how many rows return (lets call **x** number of rows return).

**Sample code (c++ and SQLite):**

```
while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        printf("\nCOLUMN1 :%s", sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
        printf("\nCOLUMN2 :%s", sqlite3_column_text(res, 1));
        printf("\nCOLUMN3 :%s", sqlite3_column_text(res, 2));
    }
```

Now I need to create a method to return this result as any given format.
**How to implement this type of task** ? (ex: using structure, multidimensional array, etc..)

**Edited:**
I've done this:

```
struct SELECTDATA
{
    const unsigned char* id;
    const unsigned char* deviceId;
    const unsigned char* deviceName;
};

vector<SELECTDATA> SQLiteHelperEx::GetData(string query)
{
    vector<SELECTDATA> vectorSelect;
    int status = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), query.size(), &res, &tail);
    const char* error_msg{ NULL };
    if (status != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        error_msg = sqlite3_errmsg(db);
        _(error_msg);
        sqlite3_finalize(res);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    else {
        SELECTDATA data_{  NULL, NULL, NULL };  
        while (sqlite3_step(res) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            data_.id = sqlite3_column_text(res, 0);
            data_.deviceId = sqlite3_column_text(res, 1);           
            data_.deviceName = sqlite3_column_text(res, 2); 
            vectorSelect.push_back(data_);
        }

    }
    return vectorSelect;
}
```

But I don't know above method was best approach or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few unknowns here to be able to provide a more detalied response, so I will try to suggest a generic solution.

First of all, you would have to handle different types of data that the SQL query could return. This can be done by creating a universal type holder class.

Next, you could create a struct containing a two-dimensional dynamic array of the universal type holder class and two integers, defining the length of both dimensions of the array.

Of course, this means that you are using C++, not using STL, and not using any of the more sofisticated libraries that could represent a recordset obtained from a database (ADO or anything like that).

This approach is generic in the sense that it would work on all queries and all types of data. Now, if you are using vectors, as can be seen from your edited question, then the two dimensional array is not needed. The struct would hold just a single dimensional dynamic array, representing one row, and one integer, representing the length of the array. This is the generic solution.

However, if you want to have hardcoded, specialized solution for that particular query, then simply create a struct with one field for each column in a resulting recordset and push it in a vector, as you have done in your example.